# angular slickgrid date format change only display in grid

Tags: angular, angular-slickgrid

```js
  this.columnDefinitions = [
          {
            id: 'edit',
            field: 'id',
            excludeFromColumnPicker: true,
            excludeFromGridMenu: true,
            excludeFromHeaderMenu: true,
            formatter: Formatters.editIcon,
            minWidth: 30,
            maxWidth: 30,
            onCellClick: (e: Event, args: OnEventArgs) => {
              this.router.navigate(['/transaction/transaction-detail/' + args.dataContext.id]);
            }
          },
         
      { id: 'cin', field: 'customer.cin', name: 'CIN', filterable: true, sortable: true, formatter: Formatters.complexObject },
      { id: 'branch', field: 'branch.name', name: 'Branch', filterable: true, sortable: true, formatter: Formatters.complexObject },
      { id: 'valueDate', field: 'valueDate', name: 'Transaction Date ',  dateFormat: 'DD-MM-YYYY'},
      { id: 'amount', field: 'amount', name: 'Amount', sortable: true, maxWidth: 200, type: FieldType.number, filter: { model: Filters.inputNumber }  },  
  ];
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="form-group row" id="grid-container">
        <angular-slickgrid gridId="transactionGrid" [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions"
                                [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [dataset]="dataset"
                                (onAngularGridCreated)="angularGridReady($event)">
        </angular-slickgrid>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to change the date format to DD-MM-YYYY OR  DD/MM/YYYY ( remove time)

How to do that in angular slickgrid

Now showng like below...date coming in date format..is we can use pipe to convert date as string

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be new to Angular-Slickgrid and SlickGrid in general and I simply say this because there is no such `dateFormat` property (I'm surprised TypeScript didn't warn you), however `formatter` does exist and so the answer is simple, you just need to use the appropriate Formatter. There are a few built-in Formatters and if you can't find the exact format that you want you also have the choice creating your own Custom Formatter.

I strongly suggest you to go through all the Wikis, for example the [Formatters - Wiki](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Formatters) would have give you the answer by looking at the list of all built-in Formatters and there's also a section to show you how to create a Custom Formatter if needed.

In your case, I think you can achieve the Format you want by doing 2 things, first call the `Formatters.dateEuro` which will give you this format `DD/MM/YYYY` and if you want to replace the `/` by a `-` then you can achieve that by using the `formatterOptions` grid option

```js
this.columnDefinitions: Column[] = [
   // ...
   { id: 'valueDate', field: 'valueDate', name: 'Transaction Date ',  formatter: Formatters.dateEuro },
];

this.gridOptions: GridOption = {
    // you can customize the date separator through "formatterOptions"
    formatterOptions: {
      // What separator to use to display a Date, for example using "." it could be "2002.01.01"
      dateSeparator: '-', // can be any of '/' | '-' | '.' | ' ' | ''
    }
};
```

I want to emphasis again all the [Wikis](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki), I spent a lot of time writing them to answers most questions, yours included. Also note, Angular-Slickgrid is wrapper on top of a jQuery library, so Angular pipes won't work neither help with your question.

Answer (score 1):

The best and easiest way to manipulate data in angular is by pipes.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'dateAgo',
  pure: true
})
export class DateAgoPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if (value) {
      const seconds = Math.floor((+new Date() - +new Date(value)) / 1000);
      if (seconds < 29) // less than 30 seconds ago will show as 'Just now'
          return 'Just now';
      const intervals = {
          'year': 31536000,
          'month': 2592000,
          'week': 604800,
          'day': 86400,
          'hour': 3600,
          'minute': 60,
          'second': 1
      };
      let counter;
      for (const i in intervals) {
          counter = Math.floor(seconds / intervals[i]);
          if (counter > 0)
              if (counter === 1) {
                  return counter + ' ' + i + ''; // singular (1 day ago)
              } else {
                  return counter + ' ' + i + 's'; // plural (2 days ago)
              }
      }
  }
    return value;
  }

}
```

And use it in html:

`{{conversation.createdAt | dateAgo}}`

You can also use reges for both js and angular

```
  formatDate(date: string): string {
    return (new Date(date)).toString().replace(/\S+\s(\S+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\s.*/, '$2-$1-$3');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer...I already have date pipe..I need to use pipes in slickgrid